# Why isn't Android's Google Assistant multilingual?

Tags: google, accessibility, google-assistant

I have configured Android with English as my system language but wanted to use Android Assistant in multilingual mode.

When speaking to it, it should be able to use Google Translate's language detection system (because, I might want to use the system in English, but talk to TalkBack in the language I have on my mind at the moment I open it.

Here is an example of my session:

1. I clicked the Google Assistant button.
2. I said, *aiutami ad usate TalkBack*, which in Italian means, *help me use TalkBack*.
3. TalkBack opened with YouTube video results with the question: *are you tell me Lucera TalkBack*.

In order words, TalkBack did not translate my question (and I don't know whether there is a way to configure such behavior).

Why doesn't Google support this behavior, and how can I enable it?

[image: TalkBack results]